# Unique pair checking query improving in pivot table

Tags: postgresql, join

First of all, I have a solution, but I do not know that query can be transformed to uses `join` or to more effective query. I just want to improve my skill.

I have seen an [example online](http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/rdbms-in-the-social-networks-age/38-Nodes_and_Edges_Undirected_Graphs).

So I have a pivot table which contains two column: `profile_id`, `followed_id`, each column a reference to the `Profile.id` column, this is a friend list.

I created a query to check for self-loops like:

```
profile_id | followed_id
         3 | 5
         5 | 3
```

As in the link this is a "duplication" because it represents the same relation between the profiles.

I created a query to check for duplication, this is a challenge for me. **Yes, I added unique constraints to the table, but I was curious about I can write a checker query or not**.

This is what I figured out:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
    tbl_profile_follow A,
    tbl_profile_follow B
  WHERE
    (B.profile_id = A.profile_id AND B.followed_id = A.followed_id)
    AND
    (B.profile_id = A.followed_id AND B.followed_id = A.profile_id)
```

I have thinking about there are any more effective query for this problem or not. For me it seems I cannot transform this query to `join` because my pivot table does not use `primary key`.
However if I use primary key in this pivot table and try to user `join` will I get better performance?

Of course I apply postgres specific query to learn postgresql :)

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Your query is not correct. It will give you only rows that `profile_id = followed_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query can be made easier:

```
select least(profile_id,followed_id), greatest(profile_id, followed_id), count(*)
from tbl_profile_follow 
group by least(profile_id,followed_id), greatest(profile_id, followed_id)
having count(*) > 1;
```

Using this approach you can also create a unique index on the table

```
create unique index idx_unique_pair 
   on tbl_profile_follow (least(profile_id,followed_id), greatest(profile_id, followed_id));
```

This above will however not prevent or detect multi-level loops:

```
profile_id | followed_id
         3 |           5
         5 |           6
         6 |           3
```

Comment: Thanks. At firstly I created the unique index :). But I wanted to create a query to myself to improve my skills. I like this easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Two remarks:

This is called an [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) table, not *pivot*.

You already do a join, you just use the old syntax:

```
 SELECT *
  FROM
    tbl_profile_follow A
  JOIN
    tbl_profile_follow B
  ON
    (B.profile_id = A.profile_id AND B.followed_id = A.followed_id)
    AND
    (B.profile_id = A.followed_id AND B.followed_id = A.profile_id)
```

This is another way to return one of the duplicte pairs:

```
SELECT profile_id, profile_id
FROM tbl_profile_follow t1
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM tbl_profile_follow t2
  WHERE t1.followed_id = t2.profile_id
    AND t1.profile_id = t2.followed_id
    AND t1.followed_id > t2.followed_id
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the associative link. I am going to learn these definitions correctly. Thank you very much for the JOIN code the ON part is very interesting. The nested query useful too :).